# Python cursor instances - mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

im currently trying to make a leaderboard command for discord, and im coming across an error when trying to get the data from my Mongo database.

```
    @commands.command()
async def leaderboard(self, ctx):
    rankings = levelling.find().sort("xp"), -1
    i = 1
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Rankings")
    for x in rankings:
        temp = ctx.guild.get_member(x["id"])
        tempxp = x["xp"]
        print(embed.add_field(name=f'{i}: {temp.name}', value=f'Total XP: {tempxp}', inline=False))
        i += 1
        if i == 11:
            break
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Command raised an exception: TypeError: index 'id' cannot be applied to Cursor instances

Answer (score 0):

```
    rankings = levelling.find().sort("xp"), -1
```

The right hand side of this assignment specifies two elements. They get combined into an array which is what gets assigned to `rankings`.

When you subsequently iterate `rankings`, you are not iterating documents in the cursor but this array, hence `x` in your code is the cursor object.

Remove the `, -1` part.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If this answer was useful you should vote it up.

Comment: @HanielBaez I did, but my account is new.